# Como saber quantas vezes uma palavra se repete no array e,a partir do retorno de uma função que calcula isso,fazer novos cálculos?(JS)

Tags: javascript, array, funções, loop, for

Preciso fazer uma função que retorne quantas vezes a placa do carro aparece no array e utilizar esse retorno em outra função para determinar um cálculo.

Esse é o meu código e ele está imprimindo "0"

```
 var placas = [
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525','AKX-3333','ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
  'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'];

var numeroDeEntradas = 0;
var pagamentoUm = 0;
var pagamentoDois = 0;

function calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placa){
   
   for (var i = 0; i < placas.length;i++){
      if (placas[i]==placas[i]){
      return   numeroDeEntradas++;
      }

   }
   
}
 
function calcularValorDevido(placa){
   
   if (calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placa)<=20){
      pagamentoUm = 20*calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placa)
   
   } else if (calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placa) >=20) {
       
       pagamentoDois= pagamentoUm +(5*(calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placa)-20))

   }
}

console.log(calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas))

console.log(calcularValorDevido(placas))
```

"pagamentoUm" e "pagamentoDois" é o valor a ser pago em função do número de vezes que a placa se repete.

Comment: `placas[i]==placas[i]` isso não deveria ser sempre igual? é como perguntar 1==1... deveria apenas somar, e retornar a variável `numeroDeEntradas` no final da função, após acabar o `for`

Comment: não dá pra entender o que exatamente quer na função calcularValorDevido na parte do if else. Não tem sentido pagamentoUm no else.

Answer (score 0):

**Usando método Array.forEach:**

```js
 var placas = [
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525','AKX-3333','ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
  'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'];

function calcularNumeroDeEntradas(array, value) {
    var count = 0;
    array.forEach((v) => (v === value && count++));
    return count;
}

console.log(calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas, 'RXB-2525'));
console.log(calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas, 'AKX-3333'));
```

**Usando método array.filter:**

```js
 var placas = [
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525','AKX-3333','ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
  'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'];



function calcularNumeroDeEntradas(array, value) {
    return array.filter((v) => (v === value)).length;
}

    console.log(calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas, 'RXB-2525'));
    console.log(calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas, 'AKX-3333'));
```

**utilizando esse retorno em outra função para determinar um cálculo**

```js
 var placas = [
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525','AKX-3333','ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'ORO-7142', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142',
   'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333','AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333',
   'RXB-2525', 'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
   'AKX-3333', 'ORO-7142', 'ORO-7142','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525',
  'AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525','AKX-3333', 'AKX-3333', 'RXB-2525'];

function calcularNumeroDeEntradas(array, value) {
    var count = 0;
    array.forEach((v) => (v === value && count++));
    return count;
}



function calcularValorDevido(quantidade){

   if (quantidade<=20){
      pagamento = 20*quantidade;
   
   } else if (quantidade >=20) {
       
       pagamento= 20*quantidade +(5*(quantidade-20))

   }
   console.log(pagamento);
}

var quant =(calcularNumeroDeEntradas(placas, 'AKX-3333'));

calcularValorDevido(quant);
```